# Symfony2 Form euro to cents

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form where I can fill in my euros, my entity only knows cents and is a integer.
So I want to create (not sure if i'm using the right method) form transformer.

What I do:

```
class EuroTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($euro)
    {
        return $euro * 100;
    }

    public function reverseTransform($euro)
    {
        return $euro / 100;
    }
}
```

form:

```
->add('price', 'money', array(
    'attr' => array(
        'style' => 'width: 70px;'
    )
))
->addModelTransformer($euroTransformer)
```

But i'm getting the next message:

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Entity\InvoiceRule, but is a(n) integer. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) integer to an instance of Entity\InvoiceRule.
```

And yes I have already a data_class in my default options.

How to solve my problem?

using symfony2 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sf2 MoneyType handles this case !

```
->add('price', 'money', array(
    'divisor' => 100,
    'attr' => array(
        'style' => 'width: 70px;'
    )
))
```

Comment: Oh damn how sweet! ty

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an object in your `reverseTransform` method:

```
/**
 * @param int $cents
 * 
 * @return InvoiceRule
 */
public function reverseTransform($cents)
{
    $euro = new InvoiceRule();
    $euro->setValue($cents / 100);

    return $euro;
}
```

And your `transform` method must transform an object into a number:

```
/**
 * @param InvoiceRule $euro
 * 
 * @return int
 */
public function transform($euro)
{
    return $euro->getValue() * 100;
}
```

See [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) for more examples.